# CASCADE when defining relations in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, sql-delete, cascading-deletes, database-relations

I'm wondering what does represent CASCADE when defining relations in InnoDB?

I see it's something related to actions: ON DELETE & ON UPDATE.

Do I have to set it to CASCADE on every relation in my tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a row is deleted and one of its member is foriegn key elsewhere then  then all rows in all tables which reference it as foreign key are also deleted.

Read:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key